# pysimplegui keys not being assigned to elements correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am trying to dynamically assign keys using pysimplegui. A simple example is updating a text field when a folder is selected.

When the layout contains two elements in each row, the text field updates correctly. However adding a third element results in the text box not updating.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg 

layout = []
elements = ["one", "two", "three"]

for element in elements:
    text = f"text_{element}"
    folder = f"folder_{element}"
    check = f"check_{element}"

    layout.append([sg.FolderBrowse(key = folder), sg.Text(key = text, size=(50, 1))])
    #layout.append([sg.FolderBrowse(key = folder), sg.Text(key = text, size=(50, 1)), sg.Checkbox(element, key=check)])
    #layout.append([sg.FolderBrowse(key = folder), sg.Text(key = text, size=(50, 1)), sg.Text(element, key=check)])

layout.append([sg.Button('Show'), sg.Cancel()])
window = sg.Window("GUI", layout)

while(True):
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
        break
    
    print(values)
    for element in elements:
        text = f"text_{element}"
        folder = f"folder_{element}"
        values[text] = values[folder]

window.close()
```

Comment: Are you reading the error messages?

Comment: Would perhaps be helpful if you read about the Browse buttons and the "target" parm in them so you understand how they change the intended target.  The PSG GitHub is a great place to ask these BTW.

Comment: Thanks @MikefromPSG. New to PSG, its really a fantastic package. I have been looking at the cookbook, but the github seems to contain some nice info so will look at that now - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The GitHub is where all the action is. Issues are where you'll get the most attention from the most experienced developers.  The Demo Programs are an important part of the PySimpleGUI System.  PySimpleGUI.org has the latest docs. PySimpleGUI.com takes you to the github.  Glad you're enjoying it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MikefromPSG, using the target param worked:

```
layout.append([sg.FolderBrowse(target = text), sg.Text(key = text, size=(50, 1)), sg.Checkbox(element, key=check)])
```